# Object variable

Tags: java, android, spinner

My code is very repetitive and I want to know if someone have a better way to do it.
Would it be possible to create a variable of `R.array.spinner_marque`?

EDIT: I have two spinners and when I click on marque my other spinner gives me other data. The problem is I need to copy the same code for every brands.

```
switch (String.valueOf(parent.getSelectedItem())) {
        case "Dunlop":
            dunlop();
            break;
        case "Falken":
            falken();
            break;
        case "Firestone":
            firestone();
            break;
        case "General Tire":
            general_tire();
            break;

private void marque() {
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
            R.array.spinner_marque, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner_marque.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void dunlop() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
            R.array.spinner_dunlop, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_serie.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void falken() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
            R.array.spinner_falken, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_serie.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void firestone() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
            R.array.spinner_firestone, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_serie.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one method that creates all these adapters

```
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> createFrom(@ArrayRes int arrayRes) {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                arrayRes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        return adapter;
    }
```

Then you can use it in your code like

```
private void marque() {
    spinner_marque.setAdapter(createFrom(R.array.spinner_marque));
}
```

Or

```
private void marque() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = createFrom(R.array.spinner_marque);
    spinner_marque.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Work perfect ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions for this kind of repetitive code, see below code

```
    private ArrayAdapter<?> inflateSpinnerAdapter(Context context, Spinner spinnerName, int spinnerArray, int spinnerLayout) {
    //Here <?> defines that return type inflateSpinner is a generic.
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
            spinnerArray, spinnerLayout);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerName.setAdapter(adapter);
    return adapter;
}
```

How to use the above function, check below code

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> marqueAdapter = inflateSpinnerAdapter(this , YOUR_SPINNER_NAME , R.array.spinner_qts , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Hope this answer will help you to understand the necessity of functions in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Define a method (contents like one of your 3 methods above) where you pass in the layout resource, you wanna use:

```
private void xyz(int arrayResourceId) { … }
```

but replace your `R.layout.[whatever]` with:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), arrayResourceId, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

For the `marque`-method this would look like

```
private void marque() {
    xyz(R.array.spinner_marque);
}
```

Comment: My problems here is, I have two R.array.spinner_marque and one of them is attach to my adapter. What I try to do is make a spinner(Dropdown menu) one with brand, size, qts. My spinner with brands got multiple brand and when I selected one brand my other spinner give me more option. Now I need to create this code for every brand. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: No sorry, please update your question with what you really wannt because I do not understand what u mean at all.

Answer (score -2):

You can check document here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#java

XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves a string array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```